# Why is my jQuery DataTable plugin not working as desired?

Tags: jquery-plugins, html-table, external, datatables, tablesorter

In response to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657387/how-can-i-use-jquery-or-css-to-sort-html-tables-by-column/24659461), I was referred to "jquery datatables plugin" which (I think) I found, but which link is not allowed here for some reason.

However, although I added the requisite libraries (one jQuery and one CSS) as "External Resources" to my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/Puf5q/) and am using precisely the same HTML and jQuery as on their sample page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            targets: [ 0 ],
            orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
        }, {
            targets: [ 1 ],
            orderData: [ 1, 0 ]
        }, {
            targets: [ 4 ],
            orderData: [ 4, 0 ]
        } ]
    } );
} );
```

...running it doesn't seem to make the table sortable.

What am I missing?

I was also referred to "[jQuery Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)" but it doesn't seem to be available on a CDN, and thus would not be available on a jsfiddle page.

### UPDATE

Actually, the aforementioned "jQuery Table Sorter" does seem to be available on a CDN, as Jason points out at the other question but, now that I've gotten the other working, I reckon I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: in my ignorance of CDN reference standards, I assumed the leading double whacks were unnecessary and removed them when adding to the External Resources. IOW, instead of pasting this:

```
cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js
```

...it needs to be this:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js
```

On reinstating the double-whacks (which looked like they were being commented out to me), it all runs fine now [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/Puf5q/1/)

Comment: glad to know . for a while i'm quite amused what going wrong i.e Data-table plugin provides sort functionality by default blah blah ..

Comment: What you are seeing is called a ["protocol-relative URL"](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).